# jquery pass deferred, promise, do ajax, right pattern to do

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I have 2 jquery pluggins (code is simplified):

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    $.fn.loadPageContent = function (url, postData) {
        url = url || window.location.href;
        postData = postData ? postData : {};
        return $.post(url, postData);
    }
})( jQuery, window, document );

(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    $.fn.infinityLoader = function (url, startPageNo, postData ) {
        var $elms = this;
        $(window).on('scroll.infinityScroll', function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
                $elms.loadPageContent(url, postData);
            }
        });
    }
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Is there a way to call infinityLoader and pass somehow promise to loadPageContent so i can be able to do:

```
$('#content').infinityLoader('http://example.com?page=', 1, {}).done(function(){
    alert('Content loaded!');
});
```

Comment: you'll need to **return** a *jQuery* `Deferred` **FROM** `infinityLoader` to be able to do that - because a) Promises do not have a `done` method, jQuery Deferred's do, and b) passing something to loadPageContent won't help infinityLoader return what is required

Answer (score 0):

Change your `infinityLoader` function like this. Remember you have to resolve `Deferred` object after completing `loadPageContent` post call.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
        $.fn.infinityLoader = function (url, startPageNo, postData) {
            var d = $.Deferred();
            var $elms = this;
            $(window).on('scroll.infinityScroll', function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
                    $elms.loadPageContent(url, postData).done(function () {

                        d.resolve();
                    });
                }
            });
            return d.promise();
        }
    })(jQuery, window, document);
```